# Filter by column WebPart in SharePoint 2013

Tags: web-part, 2013, filter

I'm in need of a column filter web part in SharePoint 2013, more specifically said i need the web part to bring content of a list, library or calender based on a column in this list, library or calender. Is there any standard function that serves my issue?

Any help would be appreciated!

Eliya Amanoeel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an plethora of filter web parts that you can connect to your list web part to use as column filters. Try out the Text Filter web part first to play around with this concept and figure out what web part connections are all about.

To get to filter web parts

- Edit Page
- Add a Web Part
- Filters Category
- Choose Text Filter

Consult [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/work-with-filter-web-parts-HA010033786.aspx) for configuring the connections.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer! I will try this and come to you with feedback.

Comment: And as usual, Microsoft has changed where the link goes to - making this answer pretty useless.

Comment: @Nullldata, I just tried the link and it still works for me.

Comment: Very strange indeed!