# Filter/Search specific fields in list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, filter

I have a custom list with two columns:

Person Name
Person Age

I want to have a search/filter area where user can search by person name or age. Name search should not be exact match and must be like "contains".

Anyway the point is I can make such web part which is not a problem. The problem is I want to display results exactly like a list is displayed in SharePoint. I don't want to use table, tr and td to display results.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use column filters on list page directly http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75955/filter-by-column-webpart-in-sharepoint-2013 Text filter requires exact match, as far as I know. Maybe options filter will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using Content Query Web Part (CQWP) to which I am passing value as query string parameter. CQWP has the option "Contains" rather than exact match which will bring all related results.